# Scanf unsigned char in hex

Tags: c, hex, scanf, unsigned-char

I am trying to change data in array, this is part of my code:

```
u_char paket[100];
//here i put some data into array and then trying to change it by user
scanf("%hhx.%hhx.%hhx.%hhx.%hhx.%hhx", &paket[0], &paket[1], &paket[2], &paket[3], &paket[4], &paket[5]);
```

When my input is for example `88.88.88.88.88.88` it sets `paket[0] - paket[5]` to 88, but it also changes `paket[6],` `paket[7]` and `paket[8]` to 0.

How is it possible and how to fix it please? I need to change only `[0] - [5]`

Comment: The declaration of your `u_char` Array might initialize all Elements to 0. the answer of some Fellow who Deleted it a Minute Ago was perhaps right: you might Scan an int aka 4 Bytes/chars upon each Format identifier on a Big-endian System.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, i didn't post whole code. Between first and second row i load data into that array. So before scanf those elements aren't set to 0, problem is with scanf.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct for C99 and later.  Presumably you are using a C standard library that does not support the `hh` length modifier, which was introduced in C99; probably the Microsoft C standard library.

If you need to support this old C standard library, you will have to rewrite your code to be C89-compatible, for example:

```
unsigned p[6];

if (scanf("%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x", &p[0], &p[1], &p[2], &p[3], &p[4], &p[5]) == 6)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        paket[i] = p[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

btw unsigned p[6]; or unsigned char p[6]; ? or doesn't matter?

Comment: @user2306381: It needs to be `unsigned p[6];`, because `%x` requires a pointer to `unsigned`, *not* a pointer to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine

```
u_char paket[100];
scanf("%hhx.%hhx.%hhx.%hhx.%hhx.%hhx", &paket[0], &paket[1], &paket[2], &paket[3], &paket[4], &paket[5])
```

Does not change the values of `paket[6], paket[7] and paket[8]`.